# Efficiency of sequential Carnot engines

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

A Carnot engine A operates between temperature $T_1$ and $T_2$ ($T_1>T_2$). A second Carnot engine B uses all the heat rejected by A as input and input and operates between temperature $T_2$ and $T_3$ ($T_2>T_3$). What will be the efficiency of the coupled engine system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the same as one Carnot engine operating between $T_1$ and $T_3$.

Hope this helps!